# JS - how can i make divs appear like in example?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myxk1.gif)

i need to make divs appear like this, or any other fancy way. Can someone provide source or something that can help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you try to write code to solve the problem? What happened when you tried that code, and how is that different from what you want to happen? Please read How to Ask. This is not a code-writing service; we aren't only interested in what the code needs to do, but specifically why and where you need help in order to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the class name of a CSS attribute with a transition, and animate property to switch it from an `opacity: 0` element to an `opacity: 1` element, and assign it an `animation` attribute that slides it in using the CSS `transform` property.

We can use `getBoundingClientRect` and `scrollTop` to check when the element is in view, and add the class when it is.

This gives us something close to the desired effect.

```js
document.addEventListener("scroll", (event) => {
  const elementsToAnimate = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".stationary"));

  for (element of elementsToAnimate) {
    const {
      scrollTop
    } = document.querySelector("html");
    const {
      top
    } = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    const containsAnimateClass = element.classList.contains("from-left");

    if (top < scrollTop / 2 && !containsAnimateClass)
      element.classList.add("from-left");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.stationary {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.from-left {
  transition: 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  animate: 1s ease slide-in-from-left;
}

@keyframes slide-in-from-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Scroll!</div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
  <div class="stationary"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple libraries already implemented these animations:

> 

https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

https://scrollrevealjs.org/

https://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/reveal_on_scroll.html

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/
(I personally love this, its easy to use)

Or in other hand make your own animation.
add event listener for scroll and create a keyframe animation. Then assign the class to the element when scroll reached to your desire number.